# In a precise way, what is the "size" of the set of continuous functions intersecting a given continuous function?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3360958/functions-based-probability), which while highly imprecise, got me thinking about a somewhat related question.

Let $C(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of continuous real functions. Say you have a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Is the set $G:=\{g\in C(\mathbb{R})| \exists x\in\mathbb{R}\text{ s.t. }f(x)=g(x)\}$ meagre? Does it depend on $f$? Is there an intuition of "size" that applies here?

I have read [this document](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math414/fs.pdf) but I don't understand how to apply this to the set I defined here. The set $G$ is not a subset of any balls centred at $f$, nor is any ball centred at $f$ a subset of $G$.

I've ruled out $G$ being comeagre. How should one proceed?

Comment: Some relevant literature: [*Behavior of continuous functions with respect to intersection patterns*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44152392) by Bruckner/Jones (1993-1994), [**Typical Properties of Continuous Functions**](http://summit.sfu.ca/item/5278) by Szpitun (1988), [*Restriction theorems in real analysis*](http://webhome.auburn.edu/~brownj4/restthm.pdf) by Brown (1994-1995), and [*Differentiability versus continuity: Restriction and extension theorems and monstrous examples*](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2019-56-02/S0273-0979-2018-01635-2/) by Ciesielski/Seoane-Sepúlveda (2019).

Comment: The document you link to deals with $C(K)$ where $K$ is compact. The metric there is clear, but what is the metric on $C(\mathbb R)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = 0$ and corresponding set $G_0$. Then
$$
\text{Int}\ G_0 = \{\textit{g: g continuous and changes sign somewhere}\} \\
\overline{G_0} = \{\textit{g: g continuous  and not separated from 0, i.e. }\inf|g| = 0\} 
$$
It is not meagre as its interior is not empty. When it comes to size, $G_0$ is what remains in $C(\mathbb{R})$ when you remove all functions of constant nonzero sign.

For arbitrary $f$ you have $G_f = f + G_0$.

Comment: Can you provide an example of sequence in $G_0$ that converges to a function that it is not in $G_0$? Indeed it is irrelevant for the question what $\overline{G_0}$ is, but I'm curious.

Comment: @ajotatxe $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\arctan(x)$ perhaps?

Comment: Is there an analogue of Lebesgue measure that applies in this case, which would make the concept of size more concrete?

Comment: Sure, $f_n(x) = 1/(1+x^2) - 1/n$ for example.

Comment: Any measure, but I can't think of one that would be Lebesgeue-like and won't yield infinites all over the place.